# How can I figure out which OCSP URL should be used for a certificate with OpenSSL?

Tags: openssl, ocsp

I have a PEM file that encodes a site's leaf certificate. I'd like to check it hasn't been revoked by querying the relevant OCSP server but I don't know which URL to use.

How can I extract the OCSP URL from the certificate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This information is exposed when you use `openssl x509` with the `-text` option:

```
$ openssl x509 -in cert.pem -noout -text
```

It's visible in the x509v3 extensions block:

```
Authority Information Access: 
  OCSP - URI:http://ocsp.int-x3.letsencrypt.org
  CA Issuers - URI:http://cert.int-x3.letsencrypt.org/
```

If you are only interested in this information, you can directly use `-ocsp_uri` instead of `-text`:

```
$ openssl x509 -in cert.pem -noout -ocsp_uri 
http://ocsp.int-x3.letsencrypt.org
```

Comment: @Mathieu Rey - Your edit was rejected for no good reason, I've approved it myself.